# How to display comment from one df in the plot of another df?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 2 dataframes like this

```
Timestamp <- c("2018-01-25 01:03:46","2018-01-25 10:09:36","2018-01-25 11:28:47")
Type <- c("Measurement","Measurement","Measurement")
Comment <- c("Positive","Negative","Positive")
df1 <- data.frame(Timestamp,Type,Comment) 
df1$Timestamp <- as.POSIXct(df1$Timestamp,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

Timestamp <- c("2018-01-25 00:03:46","2018-01-25 01:03:46","2018-01-25 08:28:47","2018-01-25 09:09:36","2018-01-25 10:28:47",
               "2018-01-25 11:03:46","2018-01-25 12:09:36","2018-01-25 14:28:47","2018-01-25 17:09:36","2018-01-25 18:28:47")
Type <- c("Measurement","Measurement","Measurement","Measurement","Measurement",
          "Measurement","Measurement","Measurement","Measurement","Measurement")
Length <- c(35,39,38,33,29,31,34,36,33,37)
df2 <- data.frame(Timestamp,Type,Length) 
df2$Timestamp <- as.POSIXct(df2$Timestamp,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

I am trying to plot df2 with the "comment" column of df1 overlayed in the plot.
When I do a merge of df1 & df2 like this

```
library(dplyr)
df_join <- left_join(df2, df1, by=c("Timestamp","Type"),all.x=T)
```

I get

```
             Timestamp        Type Length  Comment
   2018-01-25 00:03:46 Measurement     35     <NA>
   2018-01-25 01:03:46 Measurement     39 Positive
   2018-01-25 08:28:47 Measurement     38     <NA>
   2018-01-25 09:09:36 Measurement     33     <NA>
   2018-01-25 10:28:47 Measurement     29     <NA>
   2018-01-25 11:03:46 Measurement     31     <NA>
   2018-01-25 12:09:36 Measurement     34     <NA>
   2018-01-25 14:28:47 Measurement     36     <NA>
   2018-01-25 17:09:36 Measurement     33     <NA>
   2018-01-25 18:28:47 Measurement     37     <NA>
```

And so when I plot it, only the "positive" comment gets displayed in the plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(scales)
ggplot(data = df_join,aes(x=Timestamp,y=Length)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Length, colour = "Length"),size = 0.5) +                      
  geom_point(alpha=0.6, position=position_jitter(w=0.05, h=0.0), size=1) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(Timestamp, Length, label = Comment)) +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("2 hours"),labels = date_format("%m/%d %H:%M"))  + 
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

I would like to get the other comments (with their timestamps) in df1 in the same plot of df2. Is there a better way of doing it than merging the 2 dataframes?

Comment: All the comments will be included if you use `full_join` instead, but then the other ones will have `NA` for the Length column.  How do you envision plotting those other comments with no y-values?

Comment: @DavidKlotz That is where I am struggling. I was thinking of taking the point (length) that is closest to the timestamp of the missing comments and assign it that value to the NA's. I am not sure how to do that. Any suggestions?

Comment: After joining, you could arrange the dataframe by timestamp.  For the missing values, you could maybe average the lengths that occur above and below.  E.g. `(lag(Length)+lead(Length))/2`   I don't know what your data refers to, so there are probably more appropriate imputation functions.

Comment: @DavidKlotz Thanks David. I used imputeTS package and it worked well for my dataset.